# ScheduledFuture cancel(true) with a purge still executes

Tags: java, multithreading, model-view-controller, concurrency, runnable

I feel like I have read almost every post on SO about ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and ScheduledFutures and their cancellation.

Essentially, I have a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with 30 threads in the pool. I am scheduling tasks using #schedule(Runnable, delay, TimeUnit) as a way of handling timeouts. The Runnable has a very small footprint (fills a POJO with values, transforms to JSON, and sends to a REST endpoint I have setup on a server in a closed network).

```
public class MyObject {
  private String name;
  private ScheduledFuture<Void> future;

  public MyObject(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public ScheduledFuture<Void> getFuture() {
    return future;
  }

  public void setFuture(ScheduledFuture<Void> future) {
    this.future = future;
  }
}

public class TimeoutTask implements Runnable {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Build POST HTTP object

    // Send to server, receive response

    // No, I'm not catching any exceptions here (might be the issue)
  }
}

public class Util {
  private static final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor SCHEDULER = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(30);
  private static final HashMap<String, MyObject> OBJECTS = new HashMap<>();

  static {
    // Eject tasks from the queue upon cancellation
    SCHEDULER.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
    MyObject object1 = new MyObject("test");
    OBJECTS.put(object1.getName(), object1);

    MyObject object2 = new MyObject("test2");
    OBJECTS.put(object2.getName(), object2);

    MyObject object3 = new MyObject("test3");
    OBJECTS.put(object3.getName(), object3);
  }

  public static ScheduledFuture<Void> scheduleTask(int timeoutInSeconds){
    return SCHEDULER.schedule(new TimeoutTask(), timeoutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  public static void cancelTask(String name) {
    MyObject object = getObject(name);
    if (object != null){
      object.getFuture().cancel(true);
    }
  }

  public static MyObject getObject(String name) {
    return OBJECTS.get(name);
  }
}

@Controller
public class Controller {

  // REST BOILERPLATE
  @RequestMapping(...)
  public void receive(Message message) {
      if (message.getType().equals(MessageType.CANCEL)) {
          Util.cancelTask(message.getObjectName());
      }
  }
}

@Component
public class View {

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Do Something");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Util.getObject("test").setFuture(Util.scheduleTask(5));
        Util.getObject("test1").setFuture(Util.scheduleTask(15));
        Util.getObject("test2").setFuture(Util.scheduleTask(60));
      }
    });
    panel.add(button);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

I cancel the ScheduledFuture using true to allow for execution interruption and I evaluated the queue before and after to see if it is ejected and **it is but the task still runs after the delay completes**.

Any help here would be awesome. This example is very reduced, but I at least wanted to show that I'm using Spring, referencing timeouts in a common Util class (so my references aren't getting mixed up), and that this is obviously a multithreaded MVC pattern where the controller can be receiving loads of messages and spool up multiple threads to handle the receipt of these messages, which could lead to the cancellation of futures if the message type is correct.

Comment: Based on your code you could cancel only latest task. So if you submit two tasks one after another you are able to cancel only second one.

Comment: I'll update to show that I am maintaining multiple timeouts, embedded in POJOs

Comment: Crap. So I found the issue and it's outside the scope of this example. Essentially, I am working in a distributed environment and the button being clicked actually sends a UDP message across the closed network and is handled by ALL nodes running this software (not just a single node) so multiple timeouts were being scheduled as a result. The REST endpoint only cancels the server's timeout, not all the others that were accidentally running as a result of bad UDP message handling triggers. Sorry for the confusion!